# Best Data Science & Machine Learning Conferences 2019?

Tags: machine-learning, apache-spark, pyspark, pipelines

What are the best data science conferences you have attended? I am looking for a conference that will help me further develop my Data Science and Machine Learning competencies. Topics that are particularly interesting to me include model explainability, model pipelines, and model governance. I am specifically looking for a conference that have hands-on Spark training. Do you have any conference suggestions that align with my interests?

Comment: Did you try searching [on the web](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=data+science+and+machine+learning+conferences&atb=v123-6__&t=cros&ia=web)?

Comment: @mapto, yes. There are a lot of conferences on the web. However, most of them do not yet have schedules posted. So I can't filter out conferences based on content. I was looking for recommendations from others based on their experience attending a past conference.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the Strata conferences (East/West/Europe). Should hit all of your requirements.

Comment: I attended Strata last year. I was looking for some different recommendations. The conference seemed to be geared more towards infrastructure and less towards the data science practice.

Comment: The Spark AI Summit by Databricks might be the closest thing then. They have developer training + the 2019 schedule already posted. https://databricks.com/sparkaisummit/north-america/schedule. Just a note, Spark centric conferences tend to be pretty engineering/infrastructure focused by default. You may have better luck looking by looking for training opportunities that aren’t attached to a conference.